# Using LINQ in XAML Expression Editor is throwing an error

Tags: xaml, tfs

I am using the Expression Editor with a XAML I am modifying.  I am trying to use an expression like...

```
ProjectsToBuild.Select(x=>x.Replace("$VERSION", TrunkVersion).ToArray()
```

[image]

...where ProjectsToBuild is of type string[].

The XAML editor complains that ...

[image]

How do I use Linq to transform ProjectsToBuild to what I need?  I think the VB.NET syntax is the same as C# correct?

Comment: not sure if it will work, but you may be able to, if you add an Imports for System.Linq.

Comment: Yes, that's already there!  but good suggestion...